# iPhone provisional vs distribution installation on device

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to install a provisional app on the iPhone without it overwriting the distribution app? I would like to have both running since the provisional development app points to our test servers, while the distribution app, which is from the app store, points to our production servers.

Any help would be wonderful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the Bundle identifier to a different one for provisional app (other than the distribution app identifier) in this way you can have two app at the same time.